# Convert find LastRow code into a function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I use this code to get the last row number.

```vb
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = sh.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

I need to convert it into a function, I tried the following but the output is always 0.

```vb
Function LR(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    lastRow = sh.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Function
```

And using like this

```vb
Dim i As Long: i = LR(ActiveSheet)
Debug.Print i
```

Comment: Further readings at SO: [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function never returns anything.

You need to add `LR = lastRow` if you want it to return the value.

Or just return it like this (since you aren't using `LastColumn` anyway):

```
Function LR(sh As Worksheet) As Long
   LR = sh.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Last Row Function

- If the worksheet is empty, the result will be `0` (the initial value of `LR`).

```vb
Sub LRtest()
    Debug.Print LR(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
End Sub

Function LR(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long
    ' Since this will fail if the worksheet is filtered, you could add...
    'If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData ' ... to remove any filters.
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not lCell Is Nothing Then LR = lCell.Row
End Function
```